# Twitter-Bootstrap/Jquery : Dropdown doesn't lie below button, rather start from start of div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/sYLRq/

**Current**

- Click on "Add to list" and drop-down falls way left

**Required**
- Click on "Add to list" and drop-down falls just below "Add to list button"

What is wrong I am doing here?

What is that I need to fix?

Thank you

Comment: try adding `float:left;` to `div#name` - right now it's overlapping your other left floated image div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the width of your btn-group is across the whole screen. You can give it a display:inline-block; to fix:

```
<div class="btn-group open" style="display:inline-block;">
```

You should do that in css rather than inline.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sYLRq/2/)